# software to factor polynomials over finite field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I need a software/computer algebra package which allows irreducible factorization of a polynomial over finite field extensions (specifically $GF(2^{n}$)). After searching online I could only find tools for factorization over $GF(p)$ and not its extensions. Can anybody please suggest? Open source would be preferable for my usage.

Comment: Did you check GAP or Pari/GP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible with Sage (containing Pari GP), Gap, Magma and other CAS. There are several links in the web, see for example [*here*](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104061/computer-algebra-system-for-polynomial-algebras-over-finite-fields), which is explicitly for specifying the extension.